# どのようにすればxposedをフックすることができますか？

Tags: android, java

どのようにすればxposedをフックすることができますか？ 私はいくつかのアプリのすべてのメソッドをフックするために`de.robv.android.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod`をフックすることにしました。

```
package com.kyunggi.logcalls;

import android.util.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.*;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

import static de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod;

public class Main implements IXposedHookLoadPackage
{
    private String TAG="LogCall";
    public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth"))
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"Not: "+lpparam.packageName);
            return;
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"Yes "+lpparam.packageName);  

        findAndHookMethod("de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge", lpparam.classLoader, "handleHookedMethod", Member.class, int.class,Object.class,Object.class,Object[].class,new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    Method method=(Method)param.args[0];
                    Log.v(TAG, "className " + method.getClass().getName() + ",methodName " + method.getName());
                }

            });
    }
}
```

ところが、`ClassNotFoundException`が発生します。クラスローダーの問題だとおもって、どうすれば解決できますか？

> de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers$ClassNotFoundError:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge

Answer (score 0):

私は、次のコードを使用して、システムクラスローダーを得フック自体は成功しました。

```
ClassLoader rootcl=lpparam.classLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        findAndHookMethod("de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge", rootcl, "handleHookedMethod", Member.class, int.class,Object.class,Object.class,Object[].class,new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    Method method=(Method)param.args[0];
                    Log.v(TAG, "className " + method.getClass().getName() + ",methodName " + method.getName());
                }

            });
```

ところが！

> 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132] JNI ERROR (app bug):
>   local reference table overflow (max=512) 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art    
>   (4490): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132] local reference
>   table dump: 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]   Last 10 entries (of
>   512): 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       511: 0x12c58510
>   java.lang.reflect.Method 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       510: 0x12c8b860
>   java.lang.Object[] (5 elements) 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       509: 0x12c8b840
>   java.lang.Object[] (5 elements) 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       508: 0x12c45958
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge$AdditionalHookInfo 10-18
>   18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       507: 0x12c58510
>   java.lang.reflect.Method 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       506: 0x12c8b840
>   java.lang.Object[] (5 elements) 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       505: 0x12c8b820
>   java.lang.Object[] (5 elements) 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       504: 0x12c45958
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge$AdditionalHookInfo 10-18
>   18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       503: 0x12c58510
>   java.lang.reflect.Method 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       502: 0x12c8b820
>   java.lang.Object[] (5 elements) 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]   Summary: 10-18
>   18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       245 of
>   java.lang.Object[] (5 elements) (123 unique instances) 10-18
>   18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       124 of
>   java.lang.reflect.Method (2 unique instances) 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art
>   (4490): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]       123 of
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge$AdditionalHookInfo (2 unique
>   instances) 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art     (4490):
>   art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         5 of
>   java.lang.Class (4 unique instances) 10-18 18:27:22.198 F/art    
>   (4490): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]         3 of
>   android.app.ResourcesManager (1 unique instances) 10-18 18:27:22.199
>   F/art     (4490): art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:132]        
>   3 of java.lang.String (3 unique instances)

したがって、XPOSEDフレームワークフックは良くないだと思います。